# Using CONTEXTUAL FILTER [Content: Has taxonomy term ID] while excluding one field

Tags: 8, views

I have several taxonomy reference fields and would like to use [Content: Has taxonomy term ID] to filter content based on all these fields but one (keywords).

I tried adding [Content: Has taxonomy term ID] then adding [Content: keywords] in order to exclude (keywords). But, there is no option to exclude taxonomy terms as in NodeID.

Any idea?

Comment: I am trying to understand, correct me if I am wrong. You want to exclude nodes that have a specific term reference from the keywords field. AND Include all nodes that have that specific term reference from at least one of the other fields (all fields except keywords). Is this correct? When filtering by TermA, if it is included in the keywords of a node, skip that node. If it is not included in keywords and is included in at least one of the other fields, keep it. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually your example would work, but it is more complex than what I want.

I just need to skip (keywords).

In my site, TermA might be included in only one term ref field. Therefore, we can ignore this: (if it is included in the keywords of a node, skip that node.  If it is not included in keywords and is included in at least one of the other fields, keep it.). Thanks in advance.